# Phpmyadmin import stock

Tags: phpmyadmin, size

Im trying to import a large db on phpmyadmin. When the import is done it starts with the execution of querys. one of the tables is 3.5G,but when the size reaches 1G it stops and doesent response any error... I think that the problem is with the export of the db file because its only 460 mb.Mabye there is a way to export large db files.how can fix this isue?

Comment: I solved this isue bye exportin the db with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge file to be importing through PHP (which in turn forces resource limits upon phpMyAdmin); if you have command-line access I highly recommend loading it through the `mysql` command line tool. If you don't, try using the phpMyAdmin [UploadDir function](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) or see these [other suggestions](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems).